# Why does a very strong BLAST hit get lost when I change num_alignments, num_descriptions or max_target_seqs parameter?

Tags: blast, sequence-alignment, filtering

Disclaimer: This is a self answered question for documentation purpose and I adapted this from the following [github gist](https://gist.github.com/sujaikumar/504b3b7024eaf3a04ef5). Especially from users **terrycojones** and **peterjc** as well as **sujaikumar** who raised the issue.

---

I have a strange situation. I have two BLAST databases (`20170821` and `20170824`) that both contain a certain subject sequence `LC074724`. When I query them both with a given query, `Q`, in one case (`20170824`) there is a **very strong match** and in the other (`20170821`) **no match at all**.

Why is there not even a lower quality match found although the databases are nearly the same?

```
BLAST version

$ blastn -version
blastn: 2.6.0+
 Package: blast 2.6.0, build May 11 2017 22:22:40
```

Both databases contain an identical subject sequence `LC074724`:

```
$ blastdbcmd -entry LC074724 -db 20170824 | md5
fcfbc167c7f81dfd75aad1bf3db6220b

$ blastdbcmd -entry LC074724 -db 20170821 | md5
fcfbc167c7f81dfd75aad1bf3db6220b
```

Only difference for the databases is `20170821` is just `20170824` with an extra 643 sequences. Rest is completely identical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm trying to figure out why. This will be a longer read, **Tl;dr at the end**:

### Doing a match

There is a good match of `Q` against `LC074724` in `20170824`:

```
$ blastn -outfmt '6 qaccver saccver bitscore' -db 20170824 -query Q.fasta \
  -task blastn -max_hsps 1 | grep LC074724
Q   LC074724.1  2581
```

Note that the bitscore of the `LC074724` match is `2581`.

But there is **no match** of `LC074724` **at all in** `20170821`:

```
$ blastn -outfmt '6 qaccver saccver bitscore' -db 20170821 -query Q.fasta \
-task blastn -max_hsps 1 | grep LC074724
```

The option `-outfmt '6 qaccver saccver bitscore'` tells BLAST to print the query accession number and version, the subject accession and version, and the bitscore of the match.

### What are the best hits for 20170821

So what are the bitscores of the Q matches in 20170821?

```
$ blastn -outfmt '6 bitscore' -db 20170821 -query Q.fasta -task blastn -max_hsps 1 | sort -nr | head
3301
2616
2590
2590
2563
2554
2547
2544
2540
2540
```

The bitscore of `Q` against `LC074724` in `20170824` (2581) would have placed it **in 5th position in the top 10 matches of Q**, but `LC074724` is **not matched at all** in `20170821`! The lowest bitscores matched in `20170821` is 2354.

### What's the difference between the databases?

Get the ids of the subjects in each database

```
$ blastdbcmd -entry all -db 20170824 | egrep '^>' | cut -c2- | sort > 20170824.ids
$ blastdbcmd -entry all -db 20170821 | egrep '^>' | cut -c2- | sort > 20170821.ids

$ wc -l 2017082?.ids
    9754 20170821.ids
    9111 20170824.ids
   18865 total
```

`20170821` has 643 sequences that are not in `20170824`:

```
$ comm -23 20170821.ids 20170824.ids | wc -l
     643
```

`20170824` has no sequences that are not in `20170821`:

```
$ comm -13 20170821.ids 20170824.ids | wc -l
       0
```

and the two have 9111 sequences in common:

```
$ comm -12 20170821.ids 20170824.ids | wc -l
    9111
```

These numbers match with the numbers from `wc -l` above.

So `20170821` is just `20170824` with an extra 643 sequences.

### Maybe LC074724 matches, but with a low bit score?

BLAST only shows the top 500 matched subjects by default. Let's ask it to show more:

```
$ blastn -outfmt '6 qaccver saccver bitscore' -db 20170821 -query Q.fasta \
  -task blastn -max_hsps 1 -max_target_seqs 10000 > 20170821-10000-matches.txt
```

And....

```
$ head 20170821-10000-matches.txt
Q   Q   3301
Q   X234A   2616
Q   CS388973.1  2590
Q   DM059402.1  2590
Q   LC074724.1  2581
Q   KJ843188.1  2576
Q   AB697496.1  2576
Q   AB697499.1  2576
Q   AB697503.1  2576
Q   AB697508.1  2576
```

There it is! And **it's in 5th position, just as it should be** (based on the bitscores discussed above).

Just to confirm, taking away the `-max_target_seqs` option gets no match:

```
$ blastn -outfmt '6 qaccver saccver bitscore' -db 20170821 -query Q.fasta \
  -task blastn -max_hsps 1 | grep LC074724
$
```

### Three confusingly named BLAST options

I've always found the names and descriptions of the following three BLAST command-line options very confusing.

From the Formatting options section of blastn -help:

> -num_descriptions =0>   Number of database sequences to show one-line descriptions for   Not applicable for outfmt > 4
>   Default = `500'    * Incompatible with:  max_target_seqs
>
> -num_alignments =0>   Number of database sequences to show alignments for   Default = `250'    * Incompatible with: 
>   max_target_seqs

And from the Restrict search or results section:

> -max_target_seqs =1>   Maximum number of aligned sequences to keep   Not applicable for outfmt <= 4   Default = `500'    *
>   Incompatible with:  num_descriptions, num_alignments

From the section names, it seems like only the latter option (`-max_target_seqs`) would have any effect on the search, and that the former two are **just about what is displayed**.

But... using either just `-num_descriptions` or `-num_alignments` with a big value also gets a match:

```
$ blastn -db 20170821 -query Q.fasta -task blastn -max_hsps 1 -num_descriptions 10000 | grep LC074724
LC074724.1  Hepatitis B virus DNA, complete genome, isolate: p621     2581    0.0
>LC074724.1 Hepatitis B virus DNA, complete genome, isolate: p621

$ blastn -db 20170821 -query Q.fasta -task blastn -max_hsps 1 -num_alignments 10000 | grep LC074724
LC074724.1  Hepatitis B virus DNA, complete genome, isolate: p621     2581    0.0
>LC074724.1 Hepatitis B virus DNA, complete genome, isolate: p621
```

So BLAST is apparently finding the `LC074724` match even without the high `-max_target_seqs` option, but it's not displaying it unless there is a high `-num_alignments` or `-num_descriptions` value. (**Keep in mind, this is the 5th best hit! Not somewhere >500**)

Just to confirm, when none of the 3 options are given and no -outfmt option is either, the match is not found:

```
$ blastn -db 20170821 -query Q.fasta -task blastn -max_hsps 1 | grep LC074724
$
```

---

**Tl;dr:**

In summary, the options

```
 -evalue
 -max_target_seqs
 -num_alignments
 -num_descriptions
```

are **NOT** just filters applied to the results, but instead directly influence the results **found**.

This means you can End up with a **bacterial** sequence as **BEST hit** when using a value `x`, and with no bacterial sequences **at all** in your top20 when using value `y`.

To quote the NCBI user service:

> We don't consider this a bug, but I agree that we should document this
>   possibility better. This can happen because limits, including max
>   target sequences, are applied in an early ungapped phase of the
>   algorithm, as well as later.

And

> The cutoffs are applied during an ungapped extension phase, and some
>   alignments may improve in score during gapped extension. The safest
>   approach is to relax (increase) the threshold and deal with a larger
>   result set.

This was totally unexpected behaviour for me and is as far as I know is nowhere documented in the BLAST help or similar.